# can't render fullcalendar(jquery) when i try to escape single quote (/') from a string before encoding it to JSON

Tags: javascript, php, string, fullcalendar, str-replace

I'm bulding an event calendar via [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/).

i get the events from a php app that i wrote and i transfer them  to the fullcalendar via json.

the problem is that when i try to escape the single quote, the fullcalendar does nor render at all.

here is the problamrtic line code:

```
     foreach ($jsonEvent[$key1] as $key2 => $value2) {
                if ($key2 == "title") {
                    $jsonEvent[$key1][$key2] = str_replace("'","\'", $value2); //this is the problamatic line code that if excecute the fullcalendar will not render
                }
            }
        }
        $jsonString = json_encode($jsonEvent);
```

when i dont try to escape the single quote, then the fullcalendar render just fine. like in tihs code:

```
foreach ($jsonEvent[$key1] as $key2 => $value2) {
                if ($key2 == "title") {
                    $jsonEvent[$key1][$key2] = str_replace("'","", $value2); //with this line the fullcalendar render jus fine
                }
            }
        }
        $jsonString = json_encode($jsonEvent);
```

so, how can i escape the single quote(') and still get the full calendar to render?

FYI: here is the code for rendering the fullcalendar

```
 <?php  echo "<div id='calendar'></div>
<script>
                   var json = $json_array_for_fullCalendar; // this is the JSON array with the events 


$('#calendar').fullCalendar({


   events:    json,
   fixedWeekCount: false,


        });


</script>"; ?>
```

can anyone please help? many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

adding this "JSON_HEX_APOS" to the json_encode function worked worked for me

```
 $jsonString = json_encode($jsonEvent, JSON_HEX_APOS);
```

cheers!